# How do I Click a Table tag using watiN?

Tags: watin

This is the table tag which i need to click . I guess this is invokes some JS function. I dont know howto resolve it .

table id="btnTbl_compose:send_message" class="buttonTable axsButton" cellpadding="0" title="Send this message (Ctrl+Enter) | Send this message and keep existing Draft (Shift+Click)" boid="messageToolbar_compose:send_message" cmd="compose:send_message" state="normal" style="" onmouseover="Uo.Z(event, this)" unselectable="on">






Send

Answer (score 0):

I think (as far as I go your issue) this line will work for you:

```
ie.Table("btnTbl_compose:send_message").Click()
```